# Ensemble associated with a system of Photons

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, partition-function

In the book "Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics" by F. Reif it is said that :

> Photon Statistics is a special case of Bose-Einstein Statistics with no restriction on the total number of particles that the system comprises of, then the partition function in the case of Photon Statistics(Section-9.5), is written as : $$Z = \sum_{R=0} e^{-\beta(n_1e_1+n_2e_2+ ...)}$$
>
> where, $$ n_1  e_1+n_2e_2 +... = E_R$$

And using this expression, the book goes on to derive the expression for Planck Distribution.

Now how is that possible? If I am not wrong then the expression used (in this case) for the partition function is derived for a system in the Canonical Ensemble, if the number of particles is not fixed, how can you use that expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula looks like a formula in the Canonical Ensemble but is the genuine result of a Grand Canonical Ensemble calculation at the $\mu=0$ condition.

The way to see it is as follows.
The grand canonical partition function, in general, is
$$
\Xi =\sum_{N\ge 0} e^{\mu N} Q_N
$$
Where $\mu$ is the (fixed) chemical potential, and $Q_N$ is the Canonical partition function at a fixed ($N$) number of degrees of freedom.

For a separable system, the energy of a $N$-degrees of freedom state (independently whether they represent quasi-particles or else)  can be written as
$$
E(\{n_i\},N)=  \sum_i  n_i \varepsilon_i,
$$
where $\varepsilon_i$ is the eigenvalue of the $i$-th one particle state, and the values $n_i$ satisfy the constraint
$$
\sum_i n_i = N. \tag{1}
$$
Therefore, in the case $\mu=0$, we have
$$
\Xi=\sum_{N\ge 0} Q_N = \sum_{N\ge 0} \left. \sum_{\{ n_i\}} \right.^{\prime} e^{ - \beta \sum_i  n_i \varepsilon_i}.
$$
The prime on the inner summation is to recall that the configurations $\{ n_i\}$ must satisfy the constraint ($1$).

It is pretty straightforward to rewrite this last expression as
$$
\sum_{N\ge 0} \left. \sum_{\{ n_i\}} \right.^{\prime} e^{ -\beta \sum_i  n_i \varepsilon_i} = \sum_{N\ge 0} \sum_{\{ n_i\}} e^{ -\beta \sum_i  n_i \varepsilon_i} \delta_{N,\sum_i  n_i },
$$
by summing over all possible (unconstrained) values of the $\{ n_i \}$ and introducing a Kronecker's delta to take care of the constraint. In this way, we realize that by interchanging the order of summation, for each unconstrained choice of the set  $\{ n_i \}$, there is only one value of $N$ contributing to the sum. Said in another way, the sum over $N$ and the delta disappear, and we end up with
$$
\Xi =  \sum_{\{ n_i\}} e^{ -\beta \sum_i  n_i \varepsilon_i}.
$$
where each $n_i$ is independent of the value of the others and goes from $0$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two perspectives, the first one is to consider this as an effective application of the Grand Canonical Ensemble, with chemical potential $\mu=0$. However, the specific choice the chemical potential seems arbitrarily specific and needs to be justified. The underlying for this is given in the second perspective.

The reason why you need to invoke the Canonical Ensemble is because photons are quantum excitation of modes of the EM field (see second quantization for more info). Each mode acts as an independent harmonic oscillator by construction, so you are actually applying the CE on uncoupled quantum harmonic oscillators. Since in this case the spectrum is regularly spaced out with a step $\hbar\omega$, you can interpret an energy eigenfunction as the creation of a finite number of particles at the same energy. Note that you typically set the zero point energy to $0$, which does not matter in this case since it will only add an overall factor to $Z$.

Hope this helps and tell me if you find some mistakes.

Comment: There is no double perspective. In no way one is using CE. Otherwise, the number of harmonic oscillators should appear in the formulas, which is not the case.

Comment: Technically speaking, you are not allowed to use the GCE on photons, and the CE is the correct way to go. Are you familiar with the quantization of the EM field?  The number of oscillators is a actually written out, they are indexed by integers in his formula with respective frequency $e_i/\hbar$.

Comment: Why should not be allowed to use GCE for a system where the number of degrees of freedom is not fixed? That's precisely the reason for GCE. You should explain how you think it is possible to fix the number of photons.

Comment: I think you meant the number of particles not dof. The problem is the justification of $\mu=0$ which is proved in the CE. I think I wasn’t clear, the GC is applied on the quantized modes of the EM field, so the number of photons isn’t fixed. In fact mathematical formula you get is the same as your approach with $\mu=0$, which is why this heuristic is often first presented. The GC picture thus has the added benefit of justifying why $\mu=0$. Once again, I think your missing piece of the puzzle is the second quantization of the EM field.

Comment: I  think that I know the second quantization of the EM field as well as Statistical Mechanics, but  I cannot understand your idea that it would not be possible to apply the GCE to an equilibrium photon system. This is the first time I have heard about such a limitation in my life.

Comment: I’m sorry, I just realized in my previous comment that I wrote GC instead of CE. And for the comment before that, it was too radical of me to say that you can’t apply GCE. Once again, the mathematical formula you get at the end is identical. My main concern with GCE was the seemingly arbitrary condition $\mu=0$. In contrast, it arises naturally in CE which is why I find it preferable, but perhaps it is my inexperience speaking.